# How to take the snapshot of staking NFTs?

Tags: nft, staking, rewards

Last time I asked how to stake NFT without locking, and @Eddex gave me answer.

[How to stake NFT without locking?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/how-to-stake-nft-without-locking/11269#11269)

His answer is about to take the snapshot every epoch and track the NFTs so we can calculate the rewards according to the time, they are staked.

But if I have thousands of NFTs, this is really heavy work.

Can anybody suggest me the easy way to take the snapshot?

Or any other way to stake NFTs without locking and calculate the rewards.

Thank you.

Comment: How does your stake- and unstake-mechanism work? Where do you keep track of what NFTs are staked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an API such as [blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io) to fetch the data about the state of your NFTs at given time.